# where to find the complete source code for swift

Tags: swift, open-source

I understand swift is open source. However, i can't seem to find the complete source code in GitHub. For example, RandomAccessCollection protocol has a property count default implementation but upon looking through the source provided in GitHub:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RandomAccessCollection.swift

the implementation of the count property is not provided. This is just one of the many examples where code provided to us in GitHub is incomplete. 
Where do we get the complete source for RandomAccessCollection protocol as an example? Thanks.

Comment: `count` is defined in a default implementation in an extension on `Collection`. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1336

Comment: Adding on to @Alexander's comment, `RandomAccessCollection` conforms to the protocol `BidirectionalCollection` which conforms to `Collection` and that is where you'll find the implementation of `count`

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, the code is complete, how can we test it before sending a PR otherwise? :)

Please remember that Swift is a Protocol-based programming language.

When a class/protocol adheres to a protocol (for example `RandomAccessCollection` adheres to `BidirectionalCollection` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RandomAccessCollection.swift#L50), which is a `Collection`) it can also inherit properties and functions already implemented (no need to implement them again).

In this case `count` is implemented [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1336).